# 4518 and Arduino

Tags: arduino, analog, ground, 7segmentdisplay

First off, disclaimer; I'm a computer scientist in the progress of my first baby steps in electronics.

I'm trying to hookup a 7segment with a 4511, 4518 and an Arduino.
The 45-series chips and the 7segment are receiving 12v, while the Arduino is getting 5v.

I've confirmed that each part of the system works as intended in isolation, i.e. when clocking the 4518, it increments the binary output, which is correctly feeded into the 4511 and to the 7segment.

The Arduino does nothing, but a square wave currently, my questions are regarding the connection between the 4518 and the Arduino.

1. Can I safely connect the Arduino GND and the 12V GND?
2. Can I connect the 5v Arduino output pin directly to the 4518's input clock pin?
3. If (answer(Q2) == false): How should I do the connection?

   - (Assuming answer(Q1) == true): Via a transistor?
   - (Assuming answer(Q1) == false): Via an optocoupler?

I havn't decided on the source of my 5V and 12V, but for the above questions, let's assume an ATX power supply (i.e. molex {5v,GND,GND,12v}).

Comment: Why would you not have the Arduino do the counting and decoding itself?

Comment: @Ignacio: Several reasons; 1. I'm going to be running multiple 7segments from a tiny Arduino, hence the pin reduction will come in handy. 2. As the 7segments require 12v, wouldn't I need like a transistor for each of the LEDs inside it? 3. As I'm learning I'll eventually switch the arduino to a crystal.

Comment: Which 7-segment display are you using? I find it very suspect to hear that they require 12V.

Comment: @Ignacio: They are 5cm ones from China, they barely light up at 5v. Let me find the data sheet, give me 5 minutes.

Comment: They are 23011as, as I'm reading the data sheet minimum voltage is 5v; http://tinyurl.com/ow68muc

Comment: [This answer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/144961/11606) provides an alternative to having to handle the 12V directly, and lets you use as many as you like in a single chain. Although the ones listed there will work with the 23011B, not the A.

Comment: I'm sorry for my incompetency, but I need to get this straight; You're suggesting me to sack my 45xx chips for a smarter chip, which in essence does the same thing, but also handles all 12v fuzziness for me?

Comment: More like leave the counting and decoding to the Arduino, and let the other chip handle the high voltages.

Comment: Ahh, right, but what if I was going to replace the arduino with a crystal then? I.e. for the clock signal in the current design.

Comment: Then it wouldn't work, since you'd have nothing to count and decode with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. yes - you must connect all the grounds together.
2. No - the Aduino's 5 volt High (probably) won't be recognized as a high by the 4518 running on 12 volts.
3. Use an NPN transistor and a pull-up resistor:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7DBsl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
Note that the transistor will invert the signal - a high output from the Arduino will be a low input to the 4518.

Comment: Can you explain, or point me to a video lecture, alike explaining the different transistor types? :)

Comment: I !!must!! connect the ground, or I may? - Can you elaborate on that? - Couldn't I keep the two grounds and powers separated, and signal using an optocoupler, and if so, what would be the pros/cons of that approach?

Comment: If you want to keep the two grounds separate, you will need an optocoupler to pass the signal between the two isolated circuits.  Since you suggest using an ATX computer power supply, there is no reason to use an optocoupler, as all the outputs of the ATX supply will be referenced to a common ground.

Comment: Right, that makes sense, when would I want separate grounds? - If something is affecting the ground, high power components?

Comment: You would require separate grounds if you knew that the "ground" potentials of the two circuits were different (or couldn't be sure they were the same).  Note that, in most electronics, "ground" is just a name we give to that point in a circuit that we wish to call "zero volts", and there need not be any relation between "ground" in circuit A and "ground" in circuit B.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense, except I'm not sure I get the concept of 'ground potentials'. Nevertheless thanks for your reply :)!